# Scala IO wait during map external call

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I will start mentioning I am very new to Scala but I have now to maintain a legacy code where some new feature are being tried to be include.

I have the following code:

Where a list is coming as a parameter where a new output needs to be processed. However it seems like code is not waiting for the response to the external service when processing.

```
    def historyBet(jackpotListUser : List[JackpotBetHistory])(implicit MC: AppMarkerContext) : List[LegacyJackpotHistoryResponse] =
          for {
             bet <- jackpotListUser
             prize = jackpotIntegratorService.findJackpotByJackpotHumanId(bet.jackpotHumanId) match {         
                  case Some(jackpot : JackpotResponse) =>
                      ...
                      extra code extracting price from jackpot : JackpotResponse
                      ...
                      extra code generating result with prize

        } yield result
```

How can I do a call to jackpotIntegratorService.findJackpotByJackpotHumanId to execute at that time. instead of returning something that F[Option....?

```
    def findJackpotByJackpotHumanId(
        jackpotHumanId: JackpotHumanId
      )(implicit MC: AppMarkerContext): F[Option[JackpotResponse]] =
        jackpotIntegratorRepo.findJackpotByJackpotHumanId(jackpotHumanId)
```

where it is finally implemented as:

```
    override def findJackpotByJackpotHumanId(
        jackpotHumanId: JackpotHumanId
      )(implicit mc: AppMarkerContext): IO[Option[JackpotResponse]] =
    ... code calling an API which return the IO.
```

Thanks!

I thought I could do IO.await somewhere... but not sure where or how...
because in the "historyBet" function I got a F[] when it was an IO... so what is the syntax to be able to wait for the response and the continue?

Extra Comment:
The real issue we notice is that the method call is starting (the logs shows part of it) but the caller with in the maps continues too.

```
prize = jackpotIntegratorService.findJackpotByJackpotHumanId
this part of the code continues even when prize, which we want the final object JackpotResponse, not the IO or F.
```

Comment: It is hard to follow the code because is not properly formatted and not sure about the types of many things. But I am going to bet that what you want is to use `traverse` rather than `map` so that you can get an `IO[List[Foo]]`; instead of a `List[IO[Foo]]`

Comment: Thank @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I updated the description, removing code and adding some comments.
 I just need to be able to get the object price when calling the method findJackpotByJackpotHumanId, the type is depicted above, but I am completely lost with the Async running of that API call. It seems it starts running in a different thread so the matching is done not the Object, or event the options, but an IO.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, if your method needs to call an `IO` then it must return an `IO` unless you `unsafeRunSync` them... but, as the name suggest, you should not do that.

So the return type is now: `IO[List[LegacyJackpotHistoryResponse]`
And can be implemented like this:

```scala
def historyBet(jackpotListUser: List[JackpotBetHistory])(implicit MC: AppMarkerContext): IO[List[LegacyJackpotHistoryResponse]] =
  jackpotListUser.traverse { bet =>
    jackpotIntegratorService.findJackpotByJackpotHumanId(bet.jackpotHumanId).map {
      case Some(jackpot) =>
        // ...

      case None =>
        // ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response.
I got confuse though, jackpotListUser.traverse from List[JackpotBetHistory] doesn't have the traverse method. 
Are we missing something?

Comment: @Willthrom `import cats.syntax.all._`

Comment: Thanks. at the end was a little more difficult, so we are keeping working on this.